# Adjectival form of 'pathos'

Tags: word-choice, derivational-morphology

When describing rhetorical appeals, 'ethos' can become 'ethical,' and 'logos' can become 'logical.' But what about 'pathos'? The closest I can come up with is 'pathetic,' but some research tells me that using the word pathetic to mean 'relating to emotions' is an archaic definition. I was also considering using 'pathetical' to differentiate from the piteous connotation of 'pathetic'. Is there a more fitting word that I could use?

Comment: I always use *pathetic.* In the context of Aristotle's triad, *logical* and *ethical* do not exactly have their everyday meanings either, but put them all three together, and/or use them to modify *proof* or *appeal,* and they plainly and readily enough convey their triadic meanings to anyone who knows that triad.

Comment: I think I'd just go for *emotional*

Comment: In fact here is a link where *emotional* is used in that context. http://www.unm.edu/~exa10/The%20Rhetorical%20Appeals.htm

Comment: Note that to most people (in the US, at least) "pathos" means a tragic situation, not simply "an appeal to emotion".  So if your reader understands what you mean by "pathos" they would also presumably understand what you mean by "pathetic".

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. Your audience should hopefully either either understand your particular use of *pathetic* here, or at least you should be able to easily acquaint them with it.

Comment: @HotLicks I'd disagree about most people connecting "pathos" to tragedy. Everyone who's graduated from high school could be expected to be familiar with the meanings of logos, ethos, and pathos in terms of rhetoric.

Comment: @Nicole - You obviously went to a different high school.  In most high schools in the US "rhetoric" might be discussed for a few days in some class (English?  Speech?), and that's it.

Comment: @HotLicks we spent about a quarter discussing the application of the rhetorical appeals to arguments (US)

Comment: adjective of pathos = 2 b found in synonyms. a sample sentence would be helpful.

Comment: @lbf well,  the intended use case was a word that could function as "logical" in the phrase "logical appeal" or "ethical" in the phrase "ethical appeal" but refer to appeals made to the pathos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm reading The Rhetorical Tradition textbook and they've just used 'pathetical' in context with ethical and logical. It threw me off for a second, but it makes sense.

Comment: In the nearly 4 years since I asked this question, I have to say this most closely answers the question, and provides a pretty authoritative source for usage of the word in the right context. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Although, if you could provide an excerpt from the book using the word, I think this answer could be improved somewhat

Answer (score 4):

Yes, unfortunately, that is what "pathos" becomes, "pathetic".

It may have a more negative sound, but they both do mean the same thing: a show evoking pity and gloom.

Answer (score 1):

[Empathetic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Empathetic):

> - showing [empathy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=empathy&allowed_in_frame=0) or ready comprehension of others' states; "a sensitive and empathetic school counselor"

or [sympathetic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sympathetic) may suggest the idea: (from TFD)

> - Of, expressing, feeling, or resulting from sympathy: a sympathetic glance.
> - characterised by, feeling, or showing sympathy; understanding

Comment: Interesting, but in the context of rhetorical appeals, these words don't really fit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "pathetic" would be an adjective from the noun "pathos" (L. suffering, sensation, and akin to paschein, to suffer), just as you have for "ethos" and "logos".

There is a link to the 'suffering' there in Passion also (L. *passio-* root of "pati", to suffer/submit)

Comment: unfortunately the word pathetic has moved its meaning a little.Pathos,to incite feeling or pity? maybe you will have to coin your own word..like Pathoical..or just keep Pathos as an adjective and noun eh?

Answer (score -1):

**Emotive**.

1:  of or relating to the emotions

2:  appealing to or expressing emotion the emotive use of language

Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emotive).

Comment: I added a link to the source of the language you use in your answer. In future answers at this site, please identify the source of any quoted language you use. Thanks!

Comment: Has a connotation of "showing emotion"... even for the second definition, because which definition it is is ambiguous in most contexts

Answer (score -2):

How about "touching"?
That is, the heart being deeply touched or moved.

Comment: This doesn't really work with the context of rhetorical appeals

Comment: Pathos isn't necessarily effective, and that term isn't technical enough to be general

Answer (score -3):

The adjective form of the fourth device, Kairos, is "Kairotic". Perhaps Pathos could become "Pathotic".

Answer (score -3):

I think that it should be "pathotic".  It is a direct derivative of Pathos and no one can misread the word.  It will, naturally, refer the reader to "pathos".  Unfortunately, it's not in any dictionary, but. perhaps, it should be?